# How to configure relationships created by the User relationships module

Tags: 7, users

I've managed to get my UR module setup. My users can now add each other. However, the only problem am faced with is that when Alice adds Bob and Bob accepts the friend request, only Bob can see Alice's name in their current relationship list; in Alice's current relationship list Bob does not appear.

Furthermore, Alice does not get a confirmation when their friend request is accepted. How can i go about fixing this problem?

I am using Drupal 7 and the zen sub theme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User Relationships supports bi-directional relationships unless you have checked the "This is a one-way relationship" checkbox.

However, there is a bug in the current 7.x-1.0-alpha2 version, make sure you use 7.x-1.x-dev instead.

If the Relations module works for you, fine. But the main thing that UR provides is various user interfaces to request relationships, see/administer them in listings, approve them, see your relationships with other users when visiting their profile and tons of additional modules like integration with Privatemsg.

In fact, we plan on making UR just a fancy UI on top of the Relations project, but that's quite a way to go.

Comment: thank you very much. Out of interest, where is the "This is a one-way relationship" checkbox located?

Comment: That should be in the relationship type setting.

Answer (score 0):

For building Social Networking-style User Relationships the [Relation Module](http://drupal.org/project/Relation) may be more appropriate than a user reference because it natively allows bi-directional joins.  A User Reference is natively one-way as you have discovered.

Johan Falk has a pretty good [video of the Relation module](http://nodeone.se/node/981) explaining its use that would help get you started.

As for friend request confirmations, I would look at use the [Rules module](http://drupal.org/project/Rules) to trigger that acceptance on the friend request and have an Action of send Email where you can use tokens to build a custom message.

Comment: thanks a lot, i will check out the video. thanks again :)

Comment: User relationships (UR) is *not* the same thing as a user reference field, see my answer below.

Comment: i've just watched the video, i meant User Relationships (similar to flag friend) not user reference. Any suggestions?

Comment: Somehow overlooked that, sorry. Looks like a useful module - as I described above I've been handling similar functionality in Relation and Rules - will have to check out User *Relationships*.